# WordPress pagination shows 404 error

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination

I've the following code (simplified as I have some HTML between the PHP tags):

```
<?php $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1; ?>
<?php $args = array( 'posts_per_page' => 1, 'paged' => $paged, ); ?>
<?php query_posts($args); ?>
<?php if (have_posts()): ?>
<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
<?php the_content() ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php the_posts_pagination(); ?>
```

The problem is, when I click on the next page then it shows my 404 page.
This code is placed in the `home.php` and it is my news page.

How to fix this issue?

I've tried a lot queries on the internet, and already changed the permalink structure to default.

Comment: Why do you feel like opening a php tag on every row? This leaves any ease of readability behind.

Comment: Don't use `query_posts()` use `WP_QUERY()` instead [See why dont](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/50761/when-to-use-wp-query-query-posts-and-pre-get-posts)

Comment: @PhiterFernandes Because in my file i have some html between the php tags ;). Sorry for the unreadability.

Comment: This makes more sense, sorry.